# Set gradient behind UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, gradient

I have created a tableViewController where I'm calling this function:

```
func setTableViewBackgroundGradient(sender: UITableViewController ,let topColor:UIColor, let bottomColor:UIColor){

    let gradientBackgroundColors = [topColor.CGColor, bottomColor.CGColor]
    let gradientLocations = [0.0,1.0]

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = gradientBackgroundColors
    gradientLayer.locations = gradientLocations

    gradientLayer.frame = sender.tableView.bounds
    sender.tableView.backgroundView?.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, atIndex: 0)

}
```

with:

```
setTableViewBackgroundGradient(self, UIColor(0xF47434), UIColor(0xEE3965))
```

but all I get is this:

[image]

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to create background view and assign it to cell:

```
func setTableViewBackgroundGradient(sender: UITableViewController, _ topColor:UIColor, _ bottomColor:UIColor) {

    let gradientBackgroundColors = [topColor.CGColor, bottomColor.CGColor]
    let gradientLocations = [0.0,1.0]

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = gradientBackgroundColors
    gradientLayer.locations = gradientLocations

    gradientLayer.frame = sender.tableView.bounds
    let backgroundView = UIView(frame: sender.tableView.bounds)
    backgroundView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, atIndex: 0)
    sender.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundView
}
```

Also don't forget to set `UITableViewCell` background color to clear color:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

Comment: cell color can also be set in storyboard.

Comment: How can I add separate gradient background ? I mean, one for tableview and another one for tablecells?

Comment: This will made most of table view gradient not visible. But you can achieve same effect by adding gradient view to cell directly.