# How to change the background color of UITableViewController to gradient color on swift 3

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I want to change my UITableViewController background color as gradient color.

My code is as below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    let gradientLocations = [0.0,1.0]

    gradient.frame = view.bounds;
    gradient.colors = [primaryColor, secondaryColor]
    gradient.locations = gradientLocations as [NSNumber]?

    let backgroundView = UIView(frame: view.bounds)
    backgroundView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    tableView.backgroundView = backgroundView

    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

}
```

And it becomes black color.

I found this very similar question but it couldn't solve my problem.
[Set gradient behind UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018035/set-gradient-behind-uitableview)

[image]

Please help!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: My google search... "swift 3 gradient background".. top result.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380535/how-to-apply-gradient-to-background-view-of-ios-swift-app. Although that's not specifically for a table view, it should solve one of your problems... then all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a new project with a table view controller that contains exactly your code. All I had to do was make the cells transparent, too, just like the post you linked to said. It worked, so this made me curious. You did not show what `primaryColor` and `secondaryColor` are.

Note that you need to use `CGColor`s in `gradient.colors`. I just tried using `UIColor`s and the screen was just as black. Try using

```
gradient.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor]
```

or rather (if they are indeed of type `UIColor`)

```
gradient.colors = [primaryColor.cgColor, secondaryColor.cgColor]
```